# MVC MultiSelectList default value ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a multiselect list and specify the default values for the dropdown, but the default values I am providing are being ignored.

My controller looks like this:

```
var ProvisionFromDb = (from Provision in db.Provisions
                      orderby Provision.Provision1 ascending
                      select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              //select all items
                              Selected = true,
                              Text = Provision.AltDescription,
                              Value = Provision.Provision1.ToString()
                          }).ToList();
ViewBag.ProvisionDropdown = new MultiSelectList(ProvisionFromDb, "Value", "Text");
```

In my view, I have the following statement:

```
@Html.ListBox("ProvisionId", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.ProvisionDropdown)
```

Everything works, except for the default values not being selected. I assume this is because of MultiSelectList not recognizing the selected property in the SelectList objects. 
What is the simplest way to correct this?

Additional info: In the razor view statement, "ProvisionId" represents the name/ID of the select dropdown that is being created.

Comment: If `ProvisionId` is a property in your model, then setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored (its the value of `ProvisionId` which determines whats selected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here was to put the defaults into an overloaded MultiSelectList constructor, where the 4th parameter is an array representing values of the default selected items.

In my case, I did not need to define a model. The following worked:

```
ViewBag.ProvisionDropdown = new MultiSelectList(ProvisionFromDb, "Value", "Text", new[] {"Selected Value1","Selected Value2"});
```

A linq query could have also been used to generate this array based on the "Selected" property of SelectListItem.

Answer (score 1):

The options rendered as selected are determined by the value of what you're binding to. Here, namely, "ProvisionId". If that's a property on your model, you should use `ListBoxFor` instead and then set it to the list of `Provision1` values you want to be selected. If it's not a property on your model, you can set something like `ViewBag.ProvisionId` with that list.